# Get a character at a specified location

Tags: bash

I have a file which contain 64895 characters

```
In [95]: !wc -c 07.org                 
64895 07.org
```

How could I get the character at position 60000?

Comment: oh question: does the file have ascii? have newlines? My answer expects ascii and no newlines.

Comment: note that `wc -c` reports the number of bytes rather than the number of characters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is the `cut` command for that:

```
tr -d '\n' <  07.org | cut -c60000
```

The 1st part removes newlines; the 2nd part then prints the 60000th char (but does skip the newline char so if those need to be included in the count towards 60000 this wont work ;) )

Comment: amazing and interesting, the text visualble at position less than 60000, and the char at 60000 push the command line to the bottom and clear up the screen.

Comment: That's cuz you have newlines in the file. What this does is print 1 char -per- line and lines shorter than 60000 ... are an empty line. Need to remove newlines from log. working in it

Comment: @Algebra see if this is better :) If not: check JobDeg's answer and accept his is that is the better one for you

Answer (score 6):

If the file has newlines, then `head` and `tail` can be used to find a specific byte. For a file of ascii characters, chars are equivalent to bytes, but non-ascii unicode characters occupy multiple bytes. Also, the newline characters are counted. To get the byte at position 60000:

```
$ head -c 60000 file.txt | tail -c -1
```

To see how this works, the following loop looks at the first 9 bytes:

```
$ # First the data layout
$ echo $'123\n56\n89'
123
56
89
$ # Now get the first 9 bytes in turn
$ for i in `seq 9`; do c=`echo $'123\n56\n89' | head -c $i | tail -c -1` ; echo "$i => |$c|"; done
1 => |1|
2 => |2|
3 => |3|
4 => ||
5 => |5|
6 => |6|
7 => ||
8 => |8|
9 => |9|
```

Bytes 4 and 7 are newline characters.